# Unity WebGL multiplayer networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking, unity-webgl

I'm trying to bring old Unity game code in c# i wrote last year back to life. Its a multiplayer game using uLink, uLobby, uZone for the networking part of it.

I read just TODAY the shock that browsers will no longer support WebPlayer and i have to move all my code to use WebGL (I never heard of WebGL till today).

Is there any package like uLink out there I can use for the networking instead of writing all the WebGL networking code (server and client) myself? (it seems uLink is going away).

Sorry if im not clear in my question since I just started researching WebGL, but I cant find any networking package that uses WebGL with Unity that I can use right now, so that I can keep all my RPC code etc, or i dont know what other networking functions are out there now-a-days (I havnt written unity code in over a year).

If my question is not clear or too vague, please let me know whats is not clear or vague.

Thanks

Comment: it's a good question, but really it's for **gamedev.com**.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on Photon Unity Networking package. They support WebGL.

https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/1786

Comment: Thanks for the information, Do you know if the build in Unity Networking (NetworkManager etc) is compatible with WebGL? I keep hearing about UNET and NetworkManager, but i dont know the difference or which one supports WebGL.

Comment: Yes it's compatible. NetworkManager is just one of the classes of UNET. According to Unity documentation, you have to set NetworkManager.useWebSockets=true in order to allow WebGL clients to connect to the server. Although I was able to solve this issue with a different approach in the past. I programmed a regular socket.io client in the page, connecting to a node.js server. Then it was just a matter of cross communication between the browser and the WebGL. I think this way is very easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something like webtick.gg for this. Best networking solution available IMO. Uses Netcode and WebRTC instead of websockets, so it's a lot faster and more stable.